# Support for LaTeX expressions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

How can we add support for LaTeX expressions like [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) does?

Comment: You have to pull some legs and give your first son as a sacrifice. But yes, we do need it, just as bad as electronics.se needed it. http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192/tex-should-be-supported-on-er-like-on-math-se-et-al

Comment: Asking here is a pretty good way to get it done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MathJax is now enabled on the site.

Comment: Just tested it, works perfectly! Many thanks!